# Doctrine - Managed Entity - Fetched Entites are not managed by default

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, typo3, unit-of-work

I am using Doctrine for a typo3/cms project to enhance the power of the backend workflows.

So i had to boot doctrine all on my own. The most part of it was quite easy and i hat no problems at all. But when it came to persisting an existing entity i struggeld. Everytime i persisted an existing entity, it was created as a new one.

After some digging i came to the conclusion, that is not part of the "UnitOfWork" (->contains(entity) == false). If i registered it manually within this unit everything worked fine again.

```
$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->registerManaged($page, array('uid' => $page->getUid()), array('title' => $page->getTitle()));
```

But this can't be the end of the story.. so i still  try to figure out what when wrong with my doctrine :D

Why are my fetched entites not managed?

This is my DoctrineLoader:

```
private function createEntityManager()
{
    global $GLOBALS;

    $paths = array(
        MyT3Extension::rootDir() . '/Configuration/ORM'
    );
    $isDevMode = true;
    $typoDbConfig = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB'];

    // the connection configuration
    $dbParams = array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => $typoDbConfig['username'],
        'password' => $typoDbConfig['password'],
        'dbname'   => $typoDbConfig['database'],
        'charset'  => 'utf8'
    );

    $config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, MyT3Extension::rootDir() . '/Cache');
    $entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);


    return $entityManager;
}
```

Yml definition for orm model:

```
Vendor\TypoBundle\Entity\Page:
    type:  entity
    table: pages
    id: { uid: { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } } }
    fields:
        pid: { type: integer }
        title: { type: string }
        navTitle: { type: string, column: nav_title }
        doctype: { type: integer, column: doktype }
        isSiteroot: { type: boolean, column: is_siteroot }
        layout: { type: integer }
```

Example code for usuage is:

```
$page = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Vendor\TypoBundle\Entity\Page')->findOneBy(array());
$page->setTitle('Test');
$this->entityManager->persist($page);
$this->entityManager->flush(); // will create a new record (new uid)
```

What works is sth like:

```
$page = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Vendor\TypoBundle\Entity\Page')->findOneBy(array());

$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->registerManaged(
     $page, 
     array(
         'uid' => $page->getUid()
     ), array(
         'title' => $page->getTitle()
     )
);

$page->setTitle('Test');
$this->entityManager->persist($page);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

So.. i hope anyone can help me :D (i will look in the doctrine symfony bundle for a solution..)

Comment: Hi Dragnic, the behavior you are describing it's pretty strange. Can you outline an example in wich you are persisting such entities?

Comment: usually the registerManaged function is executed during hydration.. but i don't get it why it is skipped

Comment: I see, for what i can tell you're doing the right thing, at this point the issue should be with the unity of work or even with the construction of the entity manager; I would try to output the internal state of the UnitOfWork and maybe check the id of the entity after you retrive it from the db.

Comment: gnarf.. i found the solution.. was an typo3/extbase issues rather than an doctrine one.. sorry for that..
i post the answer below.
Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I found the solution. I used a special dependency injection "technique" in typo3 extbase.
If you specify your dependencies in as arguments of __construct() it will inject the service without any further configuration. So i just assumed, that it uses an internal 'service bus' to serve all dependencies with the same object instances, but instead it created one for each dependency request.

So i got three diffrent entity managers and obviously somehow not managed entities.. sorry to bothered you folks.

Comment: I got the exactly same problem with autowiring/binding in __construct() method.
I was not realy the same entity manager and my entities wasn't managed at all!